# What are the domain and codomain of the partial derivative of a vector-valued function of several variables?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be $C^\infty$ on its domain. What are the domain and codomain of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$? I was very surprised to see that the partial of a vector-valued function is not treated on wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

Denote $f$ as $f=(f_1,...,f_m)$. The notation $\frac{\partial f }{\partial x_i}$ probably stands for
$$
\frac{\partial f }{\partial x_i} = \left(\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_i},...,\frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_i}\right).
$$
That is a function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ just as $f$ itself. (I assume you understand what each $\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}$ means since $f_j$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$.)